# No utility classes were detected in your source files ,double-check the `content`

Tags: tailwind-css, tailwind-ui

I am trying to setup tailwind 3 , but i got the next warning .

```
No utility classes were detected in your source files. If this is unexpected, double-check the `content` option in your Tailwind CSS configuration.
```

this is my project structure

```
|_public : 
 |_index.html , 
 |_output.css  // this css file generated after i run the command | npx tailwindcss -i ./src/input.css -o ./public/output.css --watch
|_src
 |_input.css
```

tailwind.config.js

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: ["./src/**/*.{html,js}"],

  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

Comment: According to your config, html and js files should be in `src` directory

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to your code, your html files are in the `src` folder (and sub-folders)

- Put your html files in the `public` folder and properly link it with `output.css`
- Then run `npx tailwindcss -i ./src/input.css -o ./public/output.css --watch`

> You can also clone the [Tailwind boilerplate](https://github.com/abrahamebij/tailwind-boilerplate) I made using
>
> `git clone https://github.com/abrahamebij/tailwind-boilerplate`
>
> Then `npm install` and `npm run css`

Answer (score 6):

#### Why does this error occur ?

When specified content path in the `tailwind.config.css` doesn't have any `html/js` file

OR

if you are not using `tailwind-css classes` in your `html` file

```
module.exports = {
  content: ["./src/**/*.{html,js}"],  Your html and js files which is users of tailwind classes
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
};
```

This states I want to use the tailwind classes for `html/js` files under `src` directory. ***But src doesn't have any `html/js` file.***

#### Solution:

1. Change `content` in `tailwind.config.css` to have right path
2. Have `html/js` files in the specified directory.

---

#### Extra : Proper approach to follow when using `Tailwind-CLI`

##### 1. Know about your file structure. Use:

```
public
|_ tailwind_base.css 
    File from which the output.css is produced
     @tailwind base;
     @tailwind components;
     @tailwind utilities;
|_ output.css
src
|_ index.html   
   Link with the output.css using 
    <link href="../public/output.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

##### Watch it as

```
npx tailwindcss -i ./public/tailwind_base.css -o ./public/output.css --watch
```

##### Specify your `html/js` in `tailwind.config.js`

```
module.exports = {
  content: ["./src/**/*.{html,js}"],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
};
```

##### index.html file

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <link href="../public/output.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  </head>
  <body class="text-8xl">
    Hello
  </body>
</html>
```

Use `tailwindcss classes` happily in your `index.html` file

Answer (score 1):

This is worked for me. in tailwind.config.js, change your folder name "src" to "public" or you need to put your files to "src" folder

Answer (score 0):

content: ["./src/ **/*.{html,js}","./public/ **/*.{html,js}"],
You have to include all folders with html and js files

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Check this files structure

[image: files structure]

Add this to package.json

```json
    "scripts": {
        "build-css": "npx tailwindcss -i ./src/input.css -o ./dist/output.css --watch"
    },
```

Or try this command : `npx tailwindcss -i ./src/input.css -o ./dist/output.css --watch`

Answer (score 0):

This warning is actually self-explanatory. Got it after clearing the default markup from a newly bootstrapped nextjs template. The warning means no Tailwind classes were detected in your entire project, at least if you're working with react.

Simply add any Tailwind class to your project and the warning will go away.

```js
export default function Page() {
  return (
    <div className="bg-red-600">Hello World</h1>
  )
}
```