# error with linking source file path using tailwindcss

Tags: tailwind-css

This is the error message I get:

`` warn - No utility classes were detected in your source files. If this is unexpected, double-check the `content` option in your Tailwind CSS configuration. ``

I can't figure out why I get this error with tailwind. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75000591/19561788) is a very good explanation what the error is about.
I checked all my paths and can't find my mistake. I assume that one path is wrong.

My code can be found [here](https://github.com/buleva/buleva.github.io).

tailwind.config.js links to "./index.html", which is in the root folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you may be running Tailwind CSS CLI from the `tailwindcss` folder, as in:

```bash
cd tailwindcss
npx tailwindcss -i input.css -o output.css
```

In which case, `./index.html` would mean the file `tailwindcss/index.html` which does not exist and thus the warning from the CLI.

You could consider changing the path to `../index.html` if you would like to continue to initiate the `tailwindcss` command from within the `tailwindcss` folder.

Alternatively, you could run Tailwind CSS CLI from the root of the project:

```bash
npx tailwindcss -c tailwindcss/tailwind.config.js -i tailwindcss/input.css -o tailwindcss/output.css
```